# JPA fires N+1 select queries upon transaction commit

Tags: hibernate, jpa, db2, openjpa

I'm working on a performance tuning task where I found JPA N+1 queries is the root cause of the performance issue. I changed my query to use JOIN FETCH to solve the N+1 issue. All entity relationships are mapped with FetchType.LAZY for OneToMany mappings and its unidirectional, 
means I have not set the ManyToOne on child entity.

Now single JOIN query is getting fired instead if N+1. But when the transactional ejb method return, suddenly all the N+1 queries are fired. When I debug I found one behavior that if I change the transaction boundary,  N+1 queries are fired when exiting from that transactional method.

I have been facing this issue for two days. I really tired by trying all the ways. I tried criteria query, JPQL query, removed transaction (that causes another exception)

Am I missed something?  Because N+1 is pretty popular issue and of course the solutions are also well known.

I'm using OpenJPA as implementation (JPA2.1) and DB2 as database.

Any help on this is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, Db2 compiler rewrites a more better performance select statement based on current statistics data.
And here is the internal 7 steps how Db2's compiler works.

**The SQL and XQuery compiler process**
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0005292.html

```
The SQL and XQuery compiler performs several steps to produce an access plan that can be executed.

1.  Parse query
2.  Check semantics
3.  Rewrite query
4.  Pushdown analysis (federated databases only)
5.  Optimize access plan
6.  Remote SQL generation (federated databases only)
7.  Generate executable code
```

In other words, even if we send a well writing select statement, Db2 may rewrite it into more a better performance query.
So, for performance tuning task, it is recommended to start below page:

**Performance overview**
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0005414.html#c0005414
Here is snipped.

```
Performance refers to the way that a computer system behaves in response to a 
particular workload. Performance is measured in terms of system response time, 
throughput, and resource utilization.
Performance is also affected by:

    The resources that are available on the system
    How well those resources are used and shared
```

Please kindly ignore, if I don't understand your issue correctly.

Hope this helps.